# How to decompress and compress .odt and .docx?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, docx, odt

I have a LibreOffice text document that I need to decompress to edit some of the meta files, and after that I need to rebuild the text document.

I can decompress it with 7zip, but after that I'm not able to build the text document again from the decompressed directory.

How to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Decompress

`.odt` and `.docx` files are `.zip` files. You can try to decompress them as if they were regular `.zip` files.

If that doesn't work, you can change the extension from `.odt` or `.docx` to `.zip` and then decompress the file.

### Compress

Compress the folder to a `.odt` or `.docx` file.

If your zip program doesn't allow to compress to `.odt` or `.docx`, you can compress to `.zip` and then change the extension to `.odt` or `.docx`.

**Note:** You don't have to compress the directory with the decompressed files, you have to compress the contents of the directory. Thus, the compressed file will have in the root the meta files and directories, and not the directory that contains the meta files and directories.

Comment: OpenDocument (`.odt`) containers have one additional requirement: the `mimetype` file must be first in the archive and uncompressed. MS Office and LibreOffice themselves will recognize the file regardless, even if you don't ensure that, but other software (such as file managers) might not.